# Returning back to the child component after updating a value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

In my REACT Application, I have the main component called
Main.js, which calls a components called Listings.
The Listings components gets a state from the Main which has a list of items for which we will display on the screen. The Listings component then called a ListItem component.

Main.js is a class component

```
class Main extends Component {

 state = {
    Listings: {
    }
  }

componentDidMount() {
// make backend calls to get Listings. 
// each listing has multiple attributes such as name, location, likes and dislikes. 

handleLikeDisLike(ListingId){
// this function receives a ListingId and updates the number of Likes and DisLikes. 
}

return (
    <Listings props={this.state}
)

export default Main;
```

In the Listings components, I iterate over each listing and call the ListItem component with the props from the Main component

```
        let transformedListings = this.props.Listings.map(listing => {
            return <ListItem
                Listing_Location={listing.Listing_Location}
                Listing_Likes={listing.Listing_Likes}
                Listing_DisLikes={listing.Listing_DisLikes}
                Listing_Name={listing.Listing_Name}
                Listing_Description={listing.Listing_Description}
                Listing_Id={listing.Listing_Id}
                key={listing.Listing_Id}
                handleLikeDisLike={this.props.handleLikeDisLike}
            />
        });
```

ListItem Component

```
return (
<div>
     <Modal show={props.show} onHide={props.handleClose}>
        <Modal.Body>
          <h4>{props.Listing_Name} </h4>
          <Button className="Button" variant="outline-info" ><Twemoji text=":pushpin:" /></Button>
          <Badge className="Badge" variant="light">{props.Listing_Location}</Badge>
          <Button className="Button" variant="outline-success" onClick={() => props.handleLikeDisLike(props.Listing_Id, 'Listing_Likes', props.Listing_Location)}> <Twemoji text=":+1:" /></Button> 
          <Badge className="Badge" variant="light">{props.Listing_Likes}</Badge>
          <Button className="Button" variant="outline-danger" onClick={() => props.handleLikeDisLike(props.Listing_Id, 'Listing_DisLikes', props.Listing_Location)}><Twemoji text=":-1:" /></Button>
          <Badge className="Badge" variant="light">{props.Listing_DisLikes}</Badge>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={props.handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={props.handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
</div>
)
```

Now in my component ListItem I have a modal window where I get the user to like / dislike. When the user clicks on like and dislike, the modal window closes and the listings are rendered. I want to be able to retain control in the Modal. Please can someone help me understand what would be the best way to address / design my application to retain control in the child components.

Comment: what do you mean `I want to be able to retain control in the Modal`?

Comment: @davidhu I try to like / dislike then the modal is closed and controlled is passed back to the parent component as it reloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create local state

In `ListItem` create state with copy of the props - the item properties.

like:

```
state = {
  listItem: props.item
}
```

and handle the like and dislike change on `ListItem` component.

and on `Save Changes` you can call the `handleLikeDisLike` function

Comment: let me give that a try and see how I go